# Update no Laravel 5 um campo recebendo o valor de outro campo da mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Possuo uma tabela de configuração no meu banco de dados que tem os seguintes campos: `["id", "texto", "textoOriginal"]`.
Inicialmente os valores do campo `texto` são iguais ao campo `textoOriginal`, mas o usuário pode em determinado momento alterar o valor do campo `texto`. 
Preciso criar um método que o usuário consiga **resetar** os valores originais dos parâmetros, então preciso necessariamente rodar esta query:

```
UPDATE parametros SET texto = textoOriginal
```

Mas queria fazer isso pela sintaxe do *Query Builder*, acontece que o *Laravel* atualiza o campo `texto` com a string "**textoOriginal**".
Estou fazendo assim:

```
$this->update(['texto' => 'parametros.textoOriginal']);
```

Alguém sabe fazer isso?

Comment: ja tentou fazer uma query antes do update que pegue o valor do textoOriginal ai depois voce passa esse valor no update $this->update(['texto'=>'$row->textoOriginal]); ?

Comment: Mas ai ficaria muito pesado, queria updatar tudo de uma vez. Mas acho que não tem jeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Para quem estiver com o mesmo problema basta colocar o nome do campo na expressão DB::raw('nome_coluna') desta forma:

```
$this->update(['texto' => DB::raw('textoOriginal')]);
```